# How can I set a div instead of echoing the database row?

Tags: php

How can I set a div instead of echoing my database row? I have the following code and basically I want to echo a div 20px by 20px per user that has its status offline. Here is the code:

```
 Database user

 row id
 row offline

 insert Offline 

 mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
 $result = mysql_db_query(db_name,"SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 5");

 if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

 echo "<td>" . $row['online'] . "</td>"; 

 }
```

How would I be able to echo a div instead so the code would look something like this. Here is the code:

```
 $row['online'] = $isonline;

 if($isonline = 'Offline') { 
   $isoffline = isoffline;
 }

 if ($isoffline) {
   echo " <div style='width:20px; height:20px; background:green;'></div>";
 }

 echo "<td>" . $isoffline . "</td>";
```

How can I set my div instead of echoing my rows data?

Comment: whats wrong with your div code ?.just embed some text between the div tag.

Comment: I am having issues inserting it without the if tags

Comment: whats another way of doing that?

Comment: if condition or if tag ? not clear at all

Comment: @user3011634 -- I just gave you working code. See below for my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a `DIV`. Just insert text inside of it. As I'm showing below.

```
echo " <div style='width:20px; height:20px; background:green;'> **YOUR TEXT GOES HERE** </div>";
```

Too create another within `PHP`

```
echo "<div> ... </div>":
```

This code will work for you: `PHP`

```
 $isonline = $row['online'];

 if($isonline == 'Offline') { 
         // person is offline
 } else {
         // person is online
   echo "<div class=\"online\"> YOU ARE ONLINE! </div>";
 }
```

`CSS`

```
.online { width:20px; height:20px; background-color:green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$isonline` to the constant "isoffline", which probably isn't set.

Your first `if` is missing the second equal sign.

Your second `if` is asking if $isoffline is true, which it isn't.

```
$row['online'] = $isonline;
$isoffline = "";
if ($isonline == 'Offline') {
    $isoffline =  " <div style='width:20px; height:20px; background:green;'></div>";
}

echo "<td>" . $isoffline . "</td>";
```